# Generic function bind() with Boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind

I have some C-style functions that return `0` to indicate success, and `!= 0` on error.
I'd like to "wrap" them into **`void` functions that `throw`** instead of returning a value.

I have written this helper:

```
void checkStatus(int status) {
  if (status != 0)
    // throw an error object
}
```

Then, to wrap a determinate function `int tilt(float degrees)`, I use [`boost::bind`](http://boost.org/libs/bind):

```
function<void(float)> ntilt = bind(checkStatus, bind(tilt, _1));
ntilt(30); // this will call checkStatus(tilt(30))
```

And it works great. But I'd like to have a dedicate wrapper function, so I can just do:

```
function<void(float)> ntilt = wrap(tilt);
ntilt(30); // this will call checkStatus(tilt(30))
```

It should work for *any* function/signature that returns an `int`.
What would be the best way to do it using Boost?

Comment: Might be tedious with C++ but with C++11, you might be able to do this with varadic templates easily

Comment: I'm using C++11, but I'm also interested in a C++ solution, if it's possible.

Comment: Wait, are you sure `bind(checkStatus, bind(tilt, _1));` works fine?

Comment: @sftrabbit I'm looking at that and I don't get what's it supposed to do xD

Comment: @user814628: C++11 *is* C++.

Comment: @sftrabbit it should work, see that same example at [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds)

Comment: @mfontanini `bind` within a `bind` is used to compose functions (`lambda` style), see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds Behold the hidden power of `bind`!

Comment: @Fanael: yes you're right, the distinction I was making was the old feature vs new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create several overloads to handle the different amount of parameters that your wrapped functions might take:

```
// handles 1 parameter functions
template<typename Ret, typename T0>
function<void(T0)> wrap(Ret (*fun)(T0)) {
    return bind(checkStatus, bind(fun, _1));
}

// handles 2 parameters functions    
template<typename Ret, typename T0, typename T1>
function<void(T0, T1)> wrap(Ret (*fun)(T0, T1)) {
    return bind(checkStatus, bind(fun, _1, _2));
}

// ... add more
```

Here's a C++11 implementation. You could avoid some stuff if you didn't want an `std::function`, but well, it works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct wrapper {
    typedef Ret (*function_type)(Args...);

    void operator()(Args&&... args) {
        if(fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...) != 0)
            throw std::runtime_error("Error");
    }

    function_type fun;
};

template<typename Ret, typename... Ts>
std::function<void(Ts...)> wrap(Ret (*fun)(Ts...)) {
    return std::function<void(Ts...)>(wrapper<Ret, Ts...>{fun});
}
```

[Here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2by9b0%240) is a live demo.

Comment: I see... is there a better way to do it with C++0x? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hmmm, using variadic templates, you'd need to bind all of the required placeholders.

Comment: Looking at `bind`'s own implementation, I see that it's done exactly in that way. Interesting...

Comment: @jmendeth there you go, a C++11 impementation.

Comment: Note that you could remove the `Ret` template parameter if you're completely sure that all of the functions return an `int`.

Comment: Yep, I'm completely sure. Also, what stuff could I avoid if I didn't want a `std::function`?

Comment: Not much, actually. `wrap` could just return a `wrapper<>`, instead of a `std::function`. And it'd look better if `wrapper` used the `Ret(Args)` syntax.